Running different Quarkus integration tests with different build profiles
I have a quarkus app that exposes one set of rest endpoints with one build profile and another set of rest endpoints with another profile. To do that I used the @IfBuildProfile annotation.
In my integration tests folder I would like to have a class that tests the first set of endpoints and another class that tests the second set.
Is there a way to do so?
I tried to use the annotation @TestProfile, but it does not work... I'm assuming because the profile is considered at runtime and not at compile time (but this is just a guess).
Marco.

Yeah, your guess is correct

Hi @geoand, does quarkus offer any help for that use case? Or do I have to run the tests in separated tasks and then merge the tests results on my own?

AFAIR, we don't have anything for this use case

I encountered the same issue, so I implemented the following solution to pass my tests.
All my endpoints are annotated with @IfBuildProfile.
For my tests, I used the @QuarkusTest annotation (I’m not sure if this would work with @QuarkusIntegrationTest).
To handle different profiles, I created two utility classes for my profiles, which look like this:
class ReadTestProfile : QuarkusTestProfile {
    override fun getConfigProfile(): String {
        return "read" // Activate the "read" profile
    }
}

Then, for my tests, I annotated them with @TestProfile(ReadTestProfile::class).
When the test runs, the build profile, which is set by default to test, changes, and I see the following log message:
INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile read activated.
This confirms that the read profile is being used during the test.
